# Character Intro Sound

Tags: sound-effects, sound-design

Hello,

I need to make a sound for the 'intro' of various characters.

I posted a link to 'The Snatch' where there is no sound (just music) but explains well the kind of reference I am talking about.

http://youtu.be/uvMYltA3A48

This is a quite common stile to introduce characters, do you have any other film reference where I can get inspiration from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out a film I worked on called 'El Gringo'.  We did exactly this with designed character titles, each with an added special subjective sonic identifier for the character in question.

I'm not one to usually promote my work like this, however it's worth mentioning in this instance because it seems to fit the bill for exactly what you're asking - and I can't think of another movie off the top of my head which has character titles in a similar fashion to what you mention.

Comment: @Stavrosound that's a nice example.


Answer (score 0):

I did see a good example a little while ago in a mercenary film, but now I'm struggling to remember the details. I'll update is I remember.

Will your sound motifs continue through the film or are they just used for the introductions?   If they are used through the film think about making them fairly distinct, but based on some aspect of the character.  That way the audience will be able to make the connection between the motif and the characters appearance.